# Why the file.txt is not being deployed to my server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pipeline, aws-code-deploy, aws-codebuild

In my existing aws pipeline I have the following `buildspec.yml`:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - cd media/web/front_dev
      - echo "Hello" > ../web/txt/hello.txt

artifacts:
  files:
    - ./media/web/hello.txt
```

And the `appspec.yml` has the following

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /webserver/src/public
```

But the file `hello.txt` is not being deployed to the server on the deploy phase? Once I ssh into the machine I run the following commands:

```
/webserver/src/public/media/web/hello.txt
```

But the file is not shown. Do you have any idea why?

My pipeline initially had only a source and a deployment step then I edited it in order to have a codebuild step as well.

Comment: What kind of web-container are you running - tomcat, apache?

Answer (score 0):

Check your pipeline. You may have added the build step but the deployment just fetches the code from the version control instead of the deployment. In order to solve that follow these steps:

1. Specify a name for the output artifact at the build step.
2. Select as input artifact the artifact you have placed into as output artifact at the build step.